Envoy mapping upstreams by args from query
Can I use Envoy for mapping client to upstream by argument from URI query string? If I use Nginx I can do it:
upstream web {
hash $arg_param1 consistent;
server IP_ADDRESS;
}

All clients requests proxy to same upstream server if in URI query string param1=arg1
